# Timer.Tick will not start the new EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, timer, progress-bar

Ive got this timer that will count for 10 seconds. I want a progressbar to show that, how long it will take etc, it might be 10 seconds now but it could be dynamic in the future.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    labelCapture.Text = " ";
    buttonCapture.Enabled = false;
    labelCapture.Text = "Measuring for 10 seconds...";
    timerCapture.Interval = 10000;
    timerCapture.Enabled = true;
    UseWaitCursor = true;
    timerCapture.Start();

    Program.ModalForm.progressBarFormModal.Maximum = 10;
    timerCapture.Tick += new EventHandler(timerCapture_Tick);

    capture = true;

    myFormModal.ShowDialog(this); // Where I open the ModalForm
}
```

and my event is as follows

```
void timerCapture_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Program.ModalForm.progressBarFormModal.Value != 10)
    {
        Program.ModalForm.progressBarFormModal.Value++;
    }
    else
    {
        timerCapture.Stop(); 
    }
}
```

how the modal Form gets closed

```
    private void TickToggle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        capture = false;
        timerCapture.Stop();
        UseWaitCursor = false;
        timerCapture.Enabled = false;

        myFormModal.Close(); // Close the modal form after timer is done
    }
```

Does anyone seen an error that I might have overlooked?

Comment: So what happens? I would guess this counts to 10x10 seconds... But you don't show how the modal form closes etc.

Comment: It never jumps into the event, it just skips it.

Comment: No, it won't skip it. How long did you wait?

Comment: Yea you're right it wont skip it, but the it will only jump into timerCapture_Tick event after the 10 seconds are done? why does this happen?

Comment: Because you specified 10_000 ms. That's how a Timer works.

Comment: How would I be able to update the progressBar while the timer is still going?

Comment: Set it to 1s and count 10 ticks.